# Display number of opportunity owners working on a campaign

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, dashboard

I have a requirement to display number of opportunity owners working on a campaign 
for example if a campaign has 5 opportunities in its related list, owner for one opportunity is alex, owner of other two opportunities is jhon and  owner of other other two opportunities  is elena i want to display 3 as there are 3 people working on this campaign
On click of that number i want to be able to show who is working on what 
How can i do this??

Comment: Start working on visualforce to display as per your needs

Comment: I have created a hyper link formula field  to navigate to reports and grouped by opportunity owner I cant get the number of people working on it that's my problem if i get it then i can create another field to opportunity owners number  and reference that in the formula field